# page scrolls over banner/jumbotron

Tags: jquery, html, css

so I want to recreate this effect: http://www.firstprinceproductions.ga/
where as you start scrolling, the actual content of the page scrolls over the jumbotron.
thus far I have failed to do this.
here is some of the code I have now:

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 style="text-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #000;">Team Divinity</h1>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-question"></i> About us</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share</button>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="news">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">News</h2>
            <div class="understroke"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="learnlink"><h3>Website V2.0</h3></a>
                    <p>We are currently working on the site, this message is currently being displayed manually but will later be displayed useing a data base</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="games">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Games</h2>
            <div class="understroke"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#"><h3>Test 2</h3></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/bg.jpg" class="thumbnail-image"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#"><h3>Test</h3></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/bg.jpg" class="thumbnail-image"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.navbar {
    border-bottom: none
}

.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ebebeb;
    background: url("/img/bg.jpg");
}

.understroke {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #C4C4C4
}

.thumbnail {
    background: none !important;
    color: none !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.news h2 {
    font-size: 38px;

}

.news {
    background-color: none;
    margin: auto 20px;
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
}

.learnlink {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.thumbnail-image {
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.container {
    width: 93%;

}
```

Comment: You should ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `z-index` and a `fixed:position` you can achieve this. 
Make sure your container has a top `margin`. Also make sure you give your header a width of 100% to make it stretch the page. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jemqc4tp/

Change your `container`

```
.jumbotron {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ebebeb;
    background: url("/img/bg.jpg");
}


.container {
    width: 93%;
    margin-top:200px;
    background:white;
}
```

Of course there are many ways to achieve this result this is just one way.

Comment: this is a start, although not really what I'm looking for, I'd like to have the jumbotron to resize when ever the screen resolution changes, is there any way this can be acheaved with jquiry? (again reffer to http://www.firstprinceproductions.ga/)

Comment: This isn't a web shop where we make whatever you request. If you have a problem than you post that specific problem. Tell us what you tried. We can then answer that one specific question. You question seemed to be "how can i get the header to move behind the main body content." You actually wrote: "where as you start scrolling, the actual content of the page scrolls over the jumbotron" If this answers your question than accept it and ask another. But be specific otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I'm quite new to forums like this, I just solved the problem, I had to add some more stuff to the css, change the html around and also a bit of Jquiry. though you did answer my litteraly question, thank you :)